# Network error: software caused connection abort (Trying to connect to RaspberryPi3 over SSH)

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to use PuTTy to connect to my Raspberry pi. I keep getting the error

> network error software caused connection abort

I've already tried deleting previous keys in regedit, different computers, wiring directly to my laptop, triple checking that SSH is enabled on the Raspberry pi, but still no dice.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit 1: I also changed some permissions with

> chmod 600 -R /etc/ssh

on the Raspberry pi, but that didn't do anything either.

Comment: Wrong site use [Respberry Pi Stack](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

haha I just reinstalled the OS and it works fine now ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Facing something similar.
My thoughts shared here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=172206